# Como salvar as dependências do maven dentro da pasta do projeto?

Tags: java, maven, jar

Quero salvar todas as dependencias do  projeto maven dentro da pasta do meu projeto! O que devo colocar no arquivo pom.xml?
 Existe um plugin para isso? Gostaria de um modelo de pom.xml que descreve como fazer isso.

Aqui esta o meu pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.com.aplicacao</groupId>
    <artifactId>Exemplo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1204-jdbc42</version>
        </dependency>    
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deixe o seu pom.xml semelhante ao código abaixo, ele irá criar dentro da pasta target do projeto Maven um diretório chamado "Exemplo" (que poderia ter qualquer outro nome como lib), contendo todos os `.jars` necessários para a sua aplicação.

Aqui esta  como deve ficar o seu novo pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.com.aplicacao</groupId>
    <artifactId>Exemplo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1204-jdbc42</version>
        </dependency>    
    </dependencies>
     <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                 <!--indique aqui o nome de sua classe principal-->
                            <mainClass>br.com.aplicacao.main.SuaClassePrincipal</mainClass>
                            <!--de um nome para a pasta que vai conter os .jars das dependencias-->
                            <classpathPrefix>Exemplo/</classpathPrefix> 
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                            <!-- Aqui entre as barras deve estar o nome do diretorio criado na tag classpathPrefix -->
                                ${project.build.directory}/Exemplo/
                            </outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>Exemplo</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Não é a mesma coisa da [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/175733/4808) do Julio?

Answer (score 0):

Após a tag `</dependecies>` coloque isso:

```xml
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>../lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>../lib</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>br.com.aplicacao.AppMain</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>

                <finalName>app/nomeApp</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Coloquei  o seu código mas não funcionou! Deu um erro nos codigos fontes da classes dizendoque não opera com a versão 1.5

Comment: Versão da compilação do seu projeto precisa estar > que 1.5

Comment: na tag properties coloca isso   <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>